# Conversion from Matlab to Python of Cross Power Spectral Density function

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, file-conversion, spectral-density

I am trying to convert a MATLAB program to python. I am having problems setting up the **cross power spectral density function** and obtain matching results with Matlab.

The function used in the MATLAB code is written as follows:

`[Pxy,f] = cpsd(x,y,M,round(M/2),M,fs);`

In the documentation available in my code, I read that: M = 128 (number of FFT points) and fs = 25.0 (sampling frequency [Hz]). x and y are row-vectors 1x751 of acceleration data.

The function used has six arguments, so I assume that this: `[pxy,f] = cpsd(x,y,window,noverlap,f,fs)` is the the function which the programmer intended to call from the MATLAB library, as the only one available in the documentation with six arguments (see [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cpsd.html#d122e16724))

This function returns the cross power spectral density estimates at the frequencies specified in f.
*(It bugs me that f is not defined as a frequency but the variable M is passed there and it's the number of FFT points, but let's assume this was not a mistake).*

Now, I would like to use [scipy.signal.csd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.csd.html)  to convert this function, but there are two problems:

1. The window is defined in MatLab as an integer, but the csd from scipy allows windows only as tuples, strings, or array_like objects;
2. In the csd from scipy there is not an argument that allows to returns the cross power spectral density estimates **at specific frequencies**.

For number 1 I defined a window as follows:
`window = hamming(M, sym=False)`
I choose the hamming window as it's the default one specified for when a window is passed as an integer in the csd in MATLAB (*"If window is an integer, then cpsd divides x and y into segments of length window and windows each segment with a Hamming window of that length."*) and didn't make it symmetric given that I am doing spectral analysis, so it makes sense to use a periodic window.

For number 2 I have no solution.

This is the function I set up in my python code:

```
M = 128
fs = 25.0
window = hamming(M, sym=False)
noverlap = np.round(M/2)
f, fxx = signal.csd(x,y,fs=fs,window=window,noverlap=noverlap
```

The results are not matching in terms of Pxy (cross power spectral density), but they are perfect in terms of frequencies.
These are the first elements in the matlab results:

```
1.3590e-05
3.4354e-05
4.5282e-05
6.2549e-05
5.7965e-05
4.9697e-05
5.5413e-05
```

While this is what I get from Python:

```
2.04688576e-06
3.37540142e-05
4.51821900e-05
6.19997501e-05
5.78926181e-05
5.00058106e-05
5.53681683e-05
```

I tried using the simple cross spectral density function in matlplotlib (documented here) as follows:

`fxx, f = mlab.csd(x,y,NFFT=M,Fs=fs,noverlap=noverlap)`

And I obtain more matching results, but still not perfect.

```
1.18939608e-05
3.45206717e-05
4.56902859e-05
6.45083475e-05
5.73594952e-05
5.01539145e-05
5.34534933e-05
```

The objective is not to get rid of a possible numerical error in the conversion, but to operate the cross power spectral density with a matching input

Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot in advance!!!